# Running TensorFlow on multicore devices

Tags: java, android, tensorflow

I have a basic Android `TensorFlowInference` example that runs fine in a single thread.

```
public class InferenceExample {

    private static final String MODEL_FILE = "file:///android_asset/model.pb";
    private static final String INPUT_NODE = "intput_node0";
    private static final String OUTPUT_NODE = "output_node0"; 
    private static final int[] INPUT_SIZE = {1, 8000, 1};
    public static final int CHUNK_SIZE = 8000;
    public static final int STRIDE = 4;
    private static final int NUM_OUTPUT_STATES = 5;

    private static TensorFlowInferenceInterface inferenceInterface;

    public InferenceExample(final Context context) {
        inferenceInterface = new TensorFlowInferenceInterface(context.getAssets(), MODEL_FILE);
    }

    public float[] run(float[] data) {

        float[] res = new float[CHUNK_SIZE / STRIDE * NUM_OUTPUT_STATES];

        inferenceInterface.feed(INPUT_NODE, data, INPUT_SIZE[0], INPUT_SIZE[1], INPUT_SIZE[2]);
        inferenceInterface.run(new String[]{OUTPUT_NODE});
        inferenceInterface.fetch(OUTPUT_NODE, res);

        return res;
    }
}
```

The example crashes with various exceptions including `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` and `java.lang.NullPointerException` when running in a `ThreadPool` as per the below example so I guess it's not thread safe.

```
InferenceExample inference = new InferenceExample(context);

ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NUMBER_OF_CORES);    
Collection<Future<?>> futures = new LinkedList<Future<?>>();

for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
    Future<?> result = executor.submit(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
           inference.call(randomData);
        }
    });
    futures.add(result);
}

for (Future<?> future:futures) {
    try { future.get(); }
    catch(ExecutionException | InterruptedException e) {
        Log.e("TF", e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Is it possible to leverage multicore Android devices with `TensorFlowInferenceInterface`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the `InferenceExample` thread safe I changed the `TensorFlowInferenceInterface` from `static` and made the `run` method `synchronized`:

```
private TensorFlowInferenceInterface inferenceInterface;

public InferenceExample(final Context context) {
    inferenceInterface = new TensorFlowInferenceInterface(assets, model);
}

public synchronized float[] run(float[] data) { ... }
```

Then I round robin a list of `InterferenceExample` instance across `numThreads`.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
    final int id = i % numThreads;
    Future<?> result = executor.submit(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            list.get(id).run(data);
        }
    });
    futures.add(result);
}
```

This does increase performance however
on a 8 core device this peaks at `numThreads` of 2 and only shows ~50% CPU usage in Android Studio Monitor.

Comment: I would strongly recommend against this approach. Sure, you've made it so that calls to `run` can be simultaneous, but that is only meaningful if you don't change the inputs (via calls to `TensorFlowInferenceInterface.feed()`).

Presumably, you'd want your threads to feed different inputs so that the computation can run on them. And the approach you suggested is not safe for that.

Comment: Why is it not safe for different inputs? With a minor change of storing the futures in the loop in the order of ‘id’ I’ll know which input matches with which output.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I misread and didn't notice that the calls to `feed()` and `fetch()` are within your synchronized `run()`. So I was mistaken in my comment above.

However, your approach will limit parallelism since this essentially serializes use of the TensorFlow session - only one thread can execute the model at a time.

Comment: I'm a seeing limited parallelism but isn't the [Session](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.4/tensorflow/contrib/android/java/org/tensorflow/contrib/android/TensorFlowInferenceInterface.java#L64) an instance attribute of `TensorFlowInferenceInterface` so I should have `n` sessions running in parallel for the `n`  `InferenceExample`s I create?

Comment: I clearly cannot read clearly today. Yes, if you have `n` `TensorFlowInferenceInterface` objects, then you have `n` `Session` objects. 

Though, you are loading the model `n` times as well, and if your model footprint is large, you're consuming `n` times the memory you need. But that may be orthogonal to the limits to parallelism you're seeing.

Answer (score 0):

The `TensorFlowInferenceInterface` class is not thread-safe (as it keeps state between calls to `feed`, `run`, `fetch` etc.

However, it is built on top of the TensorFlow Java API where objects of the [`Session`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/java/reference/org/tensorflow/Session) class are thread-safe.

So you might want to use the underlying Java API directly, `TensorFlowInferenceInterface`'s constructor creates a `Session` and sets it up with a `Graph` loaded from the `AssetManager` ([code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.4/tensorflow/contrib/android/java/org/tensorflow/contrib/android/TensorFlowInferenceInterface.java#L64)).

Hope that helps.